# Regex - Validation of numeric with up to 5000 number with 1 decimal places

Tags: regex

I am trying to create `regular expression` which can take numeric digits in range b/w `0 - 5000` and up to `one decimal place`.

```
i.e. 5000 , 4999.9 , 25.0 , 2500.9
```

I have tried following regex but don't know where i need to add decimal points.

```
^0*(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|5000)$
```

Comment: So, `5000.2` is not allowed, right? What about `5000.000`?

Comment: yes 5000.2 is not allowed

Comment: no 5000.000 is not allowed as it has 3 decimal places. 5000.0 is fine.

Comment: Ah, I see, I adjusted the answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal part can be defined with the `(?:[.][0-9])?` subpattern matching one or zero sequences of  a literal dot `[.]` followed with *one digit* (`[0-9]+`). However, you need to re-group the regex a bit: `5000` must be a separate alternative since it can only have `.0` decimal part:

```
^(?:0*(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])(?:[.][0-9])?|5000(?:[.]0)?)$
  ^^                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX8qO9/4)

Breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0*(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])(?:[.][0-9])?` - `0` to `4999` numbers with or without leading `0` symbols and followed with one or zero `.` + any digit (one occurrence)
- `|` - or...
- `5000(?:[.]0)?)` - `5000` optionally followed by one or zero sequence `.0`.
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Well, I think now, it is correct. I will add the description now. I am not just sure if you want to allow optional leading zeros before `5000`. If you do, you need [`^(?:0*(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]?|[1-4][0-9][0-9][0-9])(?:[.][0-9])?|5000(?:[.]0)?))$`](https://regex101.com/r/tX8qO9/5).

Comment: Note that the other answer might be more optimal to use. I just kept the original style to help understand the technique of adding anything to the existing regex.

Answer (score 2):

Best I can think of is:

```
/^(5000(\.0)?|([0-4]?\d?\d?\d)(\.\d)?)$/
```

It's basically looking at 5000 as a separate case, and for all other cases it's a bit more generic, limiting the most significant digit to 4 in case there are 4 digits.
Decimal point (+ one digit) is optional.

**Edit:**
A more thorough breakdown of the pattern:

1. Left side of the `|` is the special case for 5000. It's just the number 5000 with an optional decimal point followed by a zero.
2. Right side of the `|`:
   a. An optional digit between 0-4
   b. Followed by two more optional digits
   c. Followed by a mandatory digit
   d. Followed by an optional decimal point and a single digit

You can test if it fits [here](https://regex101.com/r/cC8hL8/2).

Comment: I see I do not have to continue with my answer :) But please provide the pattern explanation.

Comment: your answer is also right and i will keep this for future reference. Thanks

Comment: pattern explanation [link](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E(5000(%5C.0)%3F%7C(%5B0-4%5D%3F%5Cd%3F%5Cd%3F%5Cd)(%5C.%5Cd)%3F)%24%2F)

Comment: Good job! This the way of answering a regex related question: always adding a detailed description. Here, every minute symbol may crash the whole code, thus regex pattern must be explained. +1.